# UserControl Default Name from Toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

In developing some UserControls for internal use I followed this exmaple from MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712573(v=vs.100).aspx

The issue I am having is that the a default name is not getting auto generated when the tool is dragged out of the toolbox and onto the work area.

Dragging a button out gives the following information:

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,157,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

When I drag mine out I get:

```
<my:MyUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

The control does not get named by default.  Is this and other settings controllable somewhere in the code of the control?  I would have expected it to have been named something like `Name="MyUserControl1"`

Comment: Have you found a solution?